# Coffeescript and CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, coffeescript

Is there an easy way to use Coffeescript with CakePHP?  Rails has [Barista](http://github.com/Sutto/barista), but I haven't been able to find anything similar for CakePHP.  Ideally, something transparent that would compile the coffeescript to javascript on-demand, and only when it has changed.

Google results for CakePHP & Coffeescript turn up a lot of talk over a clash between the cake command, but not much in the way of using them together.  Has anyone found anything?  Or maybe ideas on how I might implement such a plugin myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I usually handle this with a build script, either in Bash or Rake (yes, Rake, its great for building PHP projects too), which compiles, concats and compresses my `.coffee` files for production. While in development I use `coffee -w` to compile the `.coffee` files on the fly.

You could automate this further by adding a post-commit hook to Git or Subversion if you like.

You should be able to extend Mark Story's [Asset Compress](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress/wiki/) plugin to do the compiling on the fly as well.

Comment: I guess a shell script is all I really need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [kohana-coffeescript](https://github.com/DanHulton/kohana-coffeescript), which to my knowledge is the only project that does what you want in PHP. Although the project is nominally for the Kohana framework, it should be fairly easy to fork it and adapt it to CakePHP.

Comment: I checked it out.  It could probably be molded into a CakePHP Helper.  Now I'm just wondering if that's a good idea, or if it would make more sense to compile it with a build script--and not add dependencies to the app.